# Linkedin v2 APi Get Follower count of a member

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

i'm developing a Linkedin app in php,
using https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client
and my principal purpose is to get the Followers count of a current member that his using this app, not the connections count

currently my request go in success,

the code is below

```
$me = $client->get(
'me?&projection=(id)',
);
// print_r($me);
$userid = $me['id'];
$profile = $client->get(
'connections/urn:li:person:'.$userid.''
);
print_r($profile);
```

But the connections api seems to return only the count of connections, the followers count is little bit different

As Linkedin say:
Connections are two-way relationships of trust between people who know each other. If you’re connected to someone, you’re following them and they’re following you by default.

Your followers will receive your posts, articles, and shares in their LinkedIn homepage feed. Members don’t have to be connected to you to follow you and receive these updates.

how can i get the Followers count with the V2 Api? is it possible?